# UIWebView in UINavigationController not scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application which is bascially a TabBar where the tabs are UINavigationControllers which move back and forth between different ViewControllers containing UIWebViews. My problem is that although I can click on the buttons for the UIWebViews, I can't scroll the content when it is larger than the screen.

Am creating the TabController

```
tabBarController = [[MainTabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];
```

When switching between tabs, I have this code:

```
WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebController" bundle:nil];
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

[wv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[wvc setTitle:[nc title]];
[wv setDelegate:self];
[wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]];
[wvc setWebpage:wv];
[wvc setView:wv];
[nc pushViewController:wvc animated:NO];
NSLog(@"NC.viewcontroller count: %d", [nc.viewControllers count]);
[nc setLastURL:requestURL];
[wvc startLoaderIndicator];

[wv release];
[wvc release];
requestOk = YES;
```

And when a link within one of the UIWebViews is clicked, I have this:

```
ItemNavigationController *nc = (ItemNavigationController *)[tabBarController selectedViewController];
WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebController" bundle:nil];
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
//wvc.view = wvc.sView;
[wvc setTitle:[nc title]];
[wv setDelegate:self];
[wv loadRequest:request];
[wvc setWebpage:wv];
[wvc setView:wv];
[nc pushViewController:wvc animated:NO];
NSLog(@"NC.viewcontroller count: %d", [nc.viewControllers count]);
[nc setLastURL:request.URL.absoluteString];
[wvc startLoaderIndicator];

[wv release];
[wvc release];
requestOk = YES;
```

Everything works perfectly, except that the WebViews don't scroll. It looks something like this:
[image: Screenshot]

[image: These pages won't scroll]

Comment: Have you considered doing this in IB rather than trying to manage it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I don't like in this code block...

```
WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebController" bundle:nil];
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
wvc.view = wvc.sView;
```

Instead create and add the subView to the view in the `viewDidLoad` block of the view controller. Furthermore, avail yourself of IB and add the WebView via the XIB and simply connect the IBOutlet and delegate.

If you insist upon doing it this way don't overwrite the view,

```
[wvc.view addSubview:wv];
```

I wrote this in a simple WebViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.google.com"]]]; 
}
```

and called it from a AppDelegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    CPWebController *webController = [[CPWebController alloc] init];

    CPNavController *navController = [[CPNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webController];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It sizes correctly, has a navbar, and scrolls correctly. Please forgive the lack of releases for code brevity.

Comment: Ah, actually I took that out. That was an old bit of code that I was trying as a workaround.

Comment: I fixed it!! It turns out that when you add the subview to the main view of the controller, you have to add the scrollview of the UIWebView, ie:
`[wvc.view addSubview:wv.scrollView];`

Comment: You shouldn't need a ScrollView to make a web view work. A web view will handle a bigger than the view sized page automatically.

Comment: But a UIWebView has an inbuilt UIScrollView called scrollView (as of iOS5 I think), which is how it manages its own scrolling. Because I was sending the UINavigationController the UIWebView and not its inbuilt UIScrollView, the UIScrollView was being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Create `WebViewController` class and inside .m  in `viewDidLoad` add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    [wv setDelegate:self];
     NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.link.com/twitter_iPhone.php"];
    [wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:wv];
}
```

Comment: Also [wv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];  can be useful

Comment: That doesn't work. I added that line to the code but it still won't scroll. And `[wv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]` doesn't make any difference as it is already enabled (otherwise the links wouldn't work)

Comment: try this [wv.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(321, 421)];

Comment: No good. I thought ContentSize should be the size of the total content though, so it would be really long for a long WebView etc.

Comment: Instead of UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] init]; use 
 wv=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're setting it with a fixed height here:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,**480**)];
```

So the content size is only going to be 480 so there's nowhere to scroll.
Try something like (0,0,320,**1000**); to test if that is the issue 
If so set the height to be the cotent size so it's dynamic

Comment: I had tried that to no avail. The issue was actually that I was using the actual UIWebView as the view for the controller being passed to the NavigationController, and not using the built-in UIScrollView. A bit confusing actually.